# Помогите разобраться с функцией printf(" %d", &переменная)

Tags: c, вывод, printf

[image: пример]Наипростейшая прога, помогите найти ошибку. может забыл какую-нибудь библиотеку...

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать этим `printf_s`? Что вы пытаетесь вывести? Где эта информация в вопросе? Описания типа "наипростейшая прога" здесь не считаются достаточными и не приветствуются.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Странно вроде бы вопрос о `си`, но присутствуют библиотеки `c++`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы выведи числовое представление **адреса** переменной; для вывода ее значения `&` не нужен:

```
printf("%d",d);
```

Answer (score 1):

&d это адрес переменной.

Надо так

```
printf_s("%d", d);
```